# Setting Custom Static Page on Wordpress returns 404 / Stylesheet wont show

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've moved my dev station to a PC from Mamp to Xammp and I've setup my Wordpress site and theme into it, but when I change the Reading settings to set the homepage as a custom static page instead of showing the latest posts, it returns the site as a 404 in Chrome/Firefox saying the webpage cannot be found. Along with that my style.less isn't appearing but all my sites content/images are showing up along with the php-echo returning.

How can I fix this problem? I've looked all over google and I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Here's what my Header.php file looks like

```
     <?php?>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?>

                      ノಠ益ಠ)ノ up, down, left, right
<head>
<title><?php wp_title('|',true,'right'); ?><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content=""/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta name="description" content="The portfolio of">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">

    <link rel="author" href="//plus.google.com/112117177196873777330/posts"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/newtheme/style.less" media="screen"/>
    <link type="text/plain" rel="author" href="/humans.txt" />

    <script src="/wordpress/wp-content/themes/newtheme/assets/js/less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
```

Comment: Revert back to the WP default theme and tell me if it loads your site? Make sure the URLs in your General Settings are correct.

Comment: The default theme works. I fixed the 404 on static pages by replacing my home-page.php top php stuff. But my style.less wont load so my site is blank/white with the content.

Comment: Not that experienced with LESS but am I right in thinking that your LESS stylesheet has to be called after your less.js? EDIT: sorry should have done my research, you have it correct.

Comment: Perhaps a problem with your directories is more plausible, seeing as you've swapped from MAMP to XAMPP. Try using `href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.less"` for example, same with your JS file too.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. I tried <link rel="stylesheet/less" href=""<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/style.less" media="screen"/> but it didn't affect the site. I wonder if it's a Xammp issue.

Comment: I see an extra quote after your href in there? Did you do that for your less.js too?

Comment: Oh cool. Yeah I fixed that but still no change :(

Comment: Try viewing the source code of the page in your browser and following the link to your less.js in your header, does it find the file?

Comment: Ah hah! I figured it out. It was this line <?php if (substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')) ob_start("ob_gzhandler"); else ob_start(); ?> that was messing everything up.  THanks for your help! :D